# SublimeText cursor moves so slow in mac and linux, why?

Tags: performance, macos, cursor, sublimetext

I have used sublime text in windows 7, mac mini and ubuntu. And I find that cursor moves so slow in mac and ubuntu. Did someone have found that? What can I do to slove this? Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be a problem of SublimeText but the setting of the keyboard repeat delay. It is changeable on both Ubuntu and Mac Os X.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer, thx! I have sloved this problem. Exactly step is there:  http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090823193018149 . Sorry I can't vote up because my reputation is so low.

Comment: @RayJoy you can click the check mark next to the answer to mark the question as resolved.